# How to get object URL of file in S3 bucket using aws-cli? (filename have emojis)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url, aws-cli

I want to eventually create a json data of all objects URLs in a private bucket. I can simply do `aws s3 ls 's3://mybucket'` to list all files. However, my cloud service need the Object URL which goes like this: `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/law!+%F0%9F%94%A5+_xyu.mp4`.

I can construct this URL, however my problem is with the rules it has in replacing the special characters, emojis, and Unicode characters. There are many of such files and I want a reliable way to construct this URL list.

I can easily access Object URL through the s3 console online (see below screenshot) but not with aws as far as I know.
Does aws-cli provide such capability to give the Object URL? If there is not such way, which policy/table AWS uses to replace those special characters?

[image: screenshot of Object URL]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108506/special-characters-in-amazon-s3-file-name

Comment: @jarmod, Thanks but as far as I get that link, it basically suggests to not have special characters in the first place. However, I have no control on that, it's a filename chosen by users in the wild and had to deal with it. Perhaps if I could find the proper unicode text to utf-8 equivalent might do the trick.

Comment: It uses [percent encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1).  Virtually any language will have some mechanism to encode a string like this.

Comment: @AnonCoward, Thanks. As I checked, AWS Object URL does not strictly follow it. I tried it with python for example. In python `urllib` it treats ' as `%27` while in AWS URL it allows it as it is i.e. `'`. Can you confirm AWS uses RFC 3986? If so, I can go with that to construct the URL.

Comment: What's the goal?  Encoding `'` as `%27` works, and some AWS SDKs, notably boto3, will do exactly that.  If you want to copy the exact behavior of the "Copy URL" button, look into however your browser implements `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @AnonCoward, Thanks. The end goal is to send the All Object URLs in form of a json file to another cloud service. I might need to check if they accept the re-format produced by my python script.